# AVCaptureSession Crashing when using webRTC

Tags: webrtc, avcapturesession

I am using `WebRTC` and its using `AVCaptureSession`. It works fine a few times but sometimes its getting crashed with this Exception.

> Assertion failed: (_internal->figCaptureSession == NULL), function
>   -[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer attachToFigCaptureSession:], file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/EmbeddedAVFoundation/EmbeddedAVFoundation-1187.37.2.1/Aspen/AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.m

Comment: same here, it just happens randomly and there is no useful debug info.

Comment: @Tina. Can you add more integration code, version WebRTC library and full stacktrace?

Comment: @Tina did you fix this?

Comment: Same problem here, has anyone found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this problem aswell. In my code i kept an instance of AVCaptureOutput and added and removed it. When trying to add the same AVCaptureOutput instance to the same capture session again, this error appeared.

This is how i solved it:

```
private var _captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput?
var captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput {
    guard let captureOutput = _captureOutput else {
        let photoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
        photoOutput.isHighResolutionCaptureEnabled = true
        _captureOutput = photoOutput
        return photoOutput
    }
    return captureOutput
}
```

Initialize the instance once when needed and when removed, also nullify it.

```
captureSession.outputs.forEach { [weak self] output in
    self?.captureSession.removeOutput(output)
    self?._captureOutput = nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Before using instance of RTCCameraPreviewView you have to nill'ify its captureSession and assert will go away. Faced same issue.